# Angular 2 to 4 upgrade, moving from Http to HttpClient

Tags: angular, upgrade

I have a large application on `Angular2` which is now ported to `Angular4`. However, it still uses the `Http` service.

I realize that `Angular4` has `HttpClient` which is said to be better than `Http` service. However, I am but apprehensive about changing to `HttpClient` since it is used in many places and corresponding unit tests.

I would like to know, what is the best way to move from `Http` to `HttpClient`? What things should I consider from code and unit tests point of view?

Another reason I would like to move to `HttpClient` is to use the interceptor? Is it necessary to change to `HttpClient` for this?

Please advise. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion, Fredrik! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my experience.

As I remember my biggest problem was to remove map in each http call.

Otherwise you just need to import HttpClientModule and inject HttpClient service instead of Http.

Also, there is some changes in unit testing. So if you have unit tests you have a bit more work. With `HttpClient` unit testing became much easier. Angular has great docs there, so I don't think it will be big problem. At least for me I did not have any problems with understanding this new stuff.

You can check this article for more information: http://brianflove.com/2017/07/21/migrating-to-http-client/.

Comment: After reading this question, I went and switched one of my apps from Http to HttpClient. It took all of five minutes, the main thing was removing the map calls on the JSON data. 

I realize this is nowhere near a comprehensive test, heh. Just my 2 cents. Seems pretty easy.... so far....

Comment: Unit tests and interdependencied has with been concerning me since its a large application with loads of dependencies. However, your answer/comments makes more confident. I have not tried it, but will take it up soon. Thanks!